# Which of the Insights shown in a Facebook Page are available through their API?

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to get the insights data from my page on Facebook as can be seen from https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME?sk=page_insights . However I do not know which of these are available through the API, except of "number of fans" and "talking about".

I have print-screened the insights of my page and posted it as an album for better understanding here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Ze1.jpg

Below is all the insights shown on the facebook page, so I will get a clear answer.

Thank you.

*Because the subject is similar to twitter api, how can I get the numbers of retweets made from my statuses each day? *(answered)*

---

Total number of fans.
Total number of friends of fans.
Weekly total reach.
People talking about this.

**LIKES  (https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME?sk=page_insights_likes)**
*Demographics* 
Gender
Age
Country
City
Language
*Where Your Likes Came From.*
New Likes
Unlikes
Like Sources

**REACH (https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME?sk=page_insights_reach)**
*Who You Reached*
Genre + Age
*How You Reached People.*
Reach -> Organic, Paid, Viral, Total 
Unique Users by frequency

*Visits to your page*
Page Views,
Unique Visitors
Total Tab Views
External Referrers

**TALKING ABOUT (https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME?sk=page_insights_talking)**
*Who Is Talking About Your Page* 
Genre + Age
*How people are talking about your page*
Talking about this
Viral Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about the insights data available through the Facebook Graph API can be found **[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/)**.

> The Page, Application and Domain objects have an insights connection of this type. Post objects also have this connection where the Post was made by a Page.
>
> **Available metrics include application and page hits, adds, removes, and likes.**

Note that you require the `read_insights` permission for the page.

[Here is an example API response](http://paste.ubuntu.com/937724/) (with `read_insights`) for a test page I just created. All of the information you posted in the question would be there (except that the page has no users, so there won't be any proper data).

You can test this with one of your own pages using the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer):

- Use `https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/` as the URL.
- Get an access token with `read_insights` (on the 'Extended Permissions' tab) checked.

Comment: So, everything shown on the facebook page insights are available ? Even for the reach, engagement of every single post like the pic at http://i.imgur.com/hZjp5.png ?

Comment: Should be, yes. Take a look at this full API response for a page when you have the `read_insights` permission: http://paste.ubuntu.com/937724/

Comment: I'm sorry that API response has no data for the most part - I just created a page to get the response (I don't have access to any real pages). You can try one of your own pages using the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Just use `https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/` as the URL, and get an access token with `read_insights` checked.

Comment: I see, I tried it through the explorer and it seems that these insights are shown there. Please tell me, the majority (maybe all) show data from the last 3 days ( with a delay of 48 hours ). Assume that I want to view "Daily Page Views from users logged into Facebook" from March 20th until April 1st. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: What you need is `page_views_login_unique`. This is available in two time periods: `day` and `week`. To do what you want, try:  `https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_views_login_unique/day?format=json&since=1332201600&until=1333238400` in the Graph API explorer.

Comment: That uses UNIX timestamps (`since` and `until`) to specify the date range (March 20th to April 1st).

Comment: If you didn't want unique users, you should use `page_views_login` instead: `https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_views_login/day?f‌​ormat=json&since=1332201600&until=1333238400`

Comment: Oh thank you. I have two more questions though ( I guess these are my final). My daily views (through api explorer) are 21 and the "end_time" shows `2012-04-15T07:00:00+0000`. My weekly views are 195 and the "end_time" shows again the same date `2012-04-15T07:00:00+0000`. The next date showing in the daily and weekly views are "2012-04-16". How come is weekly? I mean in which week is referring to?!

Comment: And the last one question, in your opinion which is the best way to handle data and maybe present graphs? "On the fly" using the API every time I need to show high amount of data, or should I save these data in database and get the data from there ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure `end_time` is always the end of the period during which the metrics were collected. If the period is `day`, the metrics were collected for the 24 hours prior to the `end_time`. For `week` it would be the 7 days prior to the `end_time`. So `2012-04-16` in `week` would be referring to the week of `2012-04-9` to `2012-04-16`.

Comment: Maybe we should move this discussion to chat - it's getting a bit lengthy for the comments. Anyhow, on the question of querying the API every time you generate a graph: if your graphs are going to be viewed frequently, it makes much more sense to cache the API data in a database, then just periodically update the database from the API, rather than always generating the graphs "on the fly" directly from the API.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10301/discussion-between-xenon-and-kaoukkos)

Comment: Xenon, I don't know but it does not let me to post on the chatroom. Here is my last answer before accepting yours ( and giving you of course the 300 rep points ). Assume that I am authenticated and authorized facebook user in my PHP page. Is it possible to create a PHP script that will save in a mySQL DB all the -for example- "daily new likes" of the page I admin since day 1 that facebook started to save my page's data? Because I want to handle these data without requesting it from the facebook api, but instead, I will run this script once and then every single day for the new day.

Comment: @Kaoukkos Certainly, that is possible. You'll need to make multiple API calls to get all that data, though - Facebook only lets you get 90 days at a time. There's no way to find a page's creation time using the API, but hopefully you'll be able to find that out. To get all the daily likes data, you could start at today and go back 90 days at a time: `https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights/page_fan_adds/day/?since=-90 days&until=today`. Use the `previous` link in the `paging` section of the response to go back another 90 days, etc.

Comment: @Kaoukkos Hope that answers all of your questions. :) By the way, you could also start at the beginning and go forwards 90 days at a time to get all the "daily new likes", either way works.

Comment: But how do I find the beginning? For example, I created a page on 03/2010. I tried to "get" the results since 03/2009 and it showed me zeros. But even I know the creation day of that specific page, I do not know the year of others. So it's kind of messy without knowing the exact month and year. I have accepted your answer and thank you for your time and support! But please if you can think a workaround, please let me know!

Comment: @Kaoukkos: I just thought I might also point out that you could take a look at [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) if you're going to be getting a lot of data from the API. As for finding the 'beginning' of the metric data, there's nothing I can find in the API to tell you that. The best you might be able to do is keep going back 90 days at a time until you get lots of consecutive zero values, and assume that's the start of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter supplies an API to get the list of all your retweeted statuses:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/retweets_of_me
```

If you poll that once a day, you should be able to get the updates with one or two API calls, which shouldn't impact your rate limits significantly.